# How to represent time intervals in R

Tags: r, time

I would  like to represent 24h time in 10 minutes interval starting from 4:00:00 am and ending at 4:00:00am (ex.4:10; 4:20; 4:30 ). Above the code that I wrote using Posixct, hourly representation - how can I represent the time in 10 minutes intervals?

Thank you

```
z<-c("04:00:00")
j<-0
time_interval<-NULL 

for (i in 1:25) #24 denotes interval of each hour plus one for 4:00 AM again 
{
  time_interval[i]<-as.POSIXct(z,format="%H:%M:%S")+j
  j<-j+60*60 # denotes number of seconds in each hour 
}

time_interval<-as.POSIXct(time_interval,origin = "1966-01-01")`enter code here`
```

Comment: Look for `seq.POSIXt`

Comment: little more help please thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses base R only and does what you want.

```
z <- "04:00:00"
start <- paste(Sys.Date(), z)
end <- paste(Sys.Date() + 1, z)
w <- seq(as.POSIXct(start), as.POSIXct(end), by = "10 mins")
time_interval <- format(w, format = "%H:%M:%S")

head(time_interval, 10)
# [1] "04:00:00" "04:10:00" "04:20:00" "04:30:00" "04:40:00"
# [6] "04:50:00" "05:00:00" "05:10:00" "05:20:00" "05:30:00"
```